# How do I specify an installation path for Unity in Unity HUB

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have just downloaded and installed UnityHUB on my laptop in the local disk F: which has 100GBs of space.

Now the problem is that when I try to install Unity Engine it tries to install it in my local disk C: which just has 10GB of space for some reasons I don't want to clear any space in local disk C: I want to install Unity in local disk F: but I don't see an option to decide the path It just by default tries to install it in my local disk C.

Any help or improvement in the question will be welcome.

Comment: Great question but I don't remember if you can do that with unity. It has been a long time since I have used it so I don't know about the version after 2017 one.

Comment: @NANO Thanks but I am installing UNITY 2019(LTS) but it also does not have that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Open Unity Hub, and click the gear icon.

[image]

2. In General tab, Set the editor's path

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much one last thing I am a new contributor to this site did I asked the question following the rules.

Comment: Then welcome to StackOverflow ^^ In  this case it seems correct to me. Here you have more information on how to properly ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you I am just a 12-year-old machine learning(expert level) game and web developer(intermediate level) I know to ask questions on this site I have to be at least 13 but you I just could not stop myself from learning more and more to improve my skills from this website.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again when I have changed the location and try to install it in my local disk F It still installs a little bit of it in local disk C can I do something so It only installs it in local disk F and not any other disk.

Comment: Your UnityHub is installed in F?

Comment: I don't know then

Answer (score 1):

### Unity Hub

1. Click Setting Gear Icon.
2. Click General Tab.
3. On Right side Unity Editors Folder click ...(Three dot on click)
4. Select Directory or create new folder after select.[ If error not enough space make sure check enough space after select another directory]
5. Select Folder.
6. Click Save Button.

---

### Best Solution:

1. Please Change another Directory and click select folder click.
2. Please select your directory or create new folder and select it.

[Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTrd2.png)

[Step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRiu3.png)

[Step 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObWq2.png)